# Getting the last element of class x using jquery 'each'

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are two `.js-type`'s classes in every row in the table of class `table` and there are many rows.

I am using the following to populate the array with all the `.js-type` objects:

```
$('.js-type').each(function(){
    myArray.push($(this).text());
});
```

My question is, is there a way for me to populate the same array with the last element found in every row in the `.table` class only?

This is what I tried:

Attempt1:

```
$('.js-type:last-child').each(function(){
    myArray.push($(this).text());
});
```

Attempt2:

```
$('.js-type:last').each(function(){
    myArray.push($(this).text());
});
```

Attempt3:

```
$('.js-type').eq(1).each(function(){
    myArray.push($(this).text());
});
```

I appreciate any advice about this.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You post an example of the structure of a row? It would be helpful to know how many cells are in each row, whether the two elements are in the same cell or different ones. If there are other elements, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The code is very large but the example is simple. The table is an html table. Each row is a regular html table row and it contains two td elements of the same class `js-type`

Comment: So each row just contains two cells with the same class? That means you want to select the second table cell in each row? You don't have to post everything, just what is relevant.

Comment: You are over complicating it. There is a table. The table has say, 100000 rows. Of these 100000 rows, 2 are of class `js-type`. I want to select the second `js-type` object from every single row in the table. Makes sense? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the last element of each row:

```
$('.table tr>*:last-child').each(function(){
    myArray.push($(this).text());
});
```

This will get you the last `.js-type` element

```
$('.table tr').find('td.js-type:last-of-type').each(function(){
        myArray.push($(this).text());
    });
```

Comment: This is will only select the last of all selected elements.

Comment: Isn't that what the OP asked for with the question: "My question is, is there a way for me to populate the same array with the last element found in every row in the .table class only?"

Comment: Yes, in *every* row, not the last element of all of them. That's what I meant. This selector will only select *one* element.

Comment: Sorry `$('.table tr>*:last-child')` will get what you want

Comment: That would select the last `td` element, not necessarily the `.js-type` element. There is simply not enough information to properly answer the question.

Comment: You asked for the last element, not the last `.js-stype` so what you actually need would be `$('.table tr').find('td.js-type:last-of-type')`

Comment: Well, the title says `Getting the last element of class x using jquery 'each'` but I agree, it's not 100% clear. Btw, I didn't ask for anything, it's not my question ;)

Comment: +1, Thanks for the reply. Your second example worked great. However, I must say that `last-of-type` did not work for me. Instead i just replaced that with `last`. Please edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
$("tr").each( function () {
    myArray.push($(this).find(".js-type").next().text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
$("table tr").each(
    function(i, e)
    {
        myArray.push( $(e).find(".js-type").eq(1).text() );
    }
);
```